# Infinite group with elements of finite order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

It is easy to construct an infinite group with all elements of finite order, e.g., the infinite direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

However, I wonder that for a given integer $n>2$, if there exists an infinite group that satisfies:

1. For each $1\le k\le n$, there exists an element of order $k$,
2. For each $k>n$ (including $k=\infty$), there does not exist an element of order $k$.

If there is no group satisfying the restriction, we can consider replacing condition 2 with

2.1 For each $k>n$ (**excluding** $k=\infty$), there does not exist an element of order $k$.

(**Update:** 1+(2.1) can be satisfied by $C_2 * C_3 * \ldots * C_n$, where $*$ is the free product. Thanks to @user10354138)

Or consider some special $n$, e.g., a prime $p$, or a factorial number $k!$.

I have no clue to solve this problem using the direct sum. For example, for $n=3$, we cannot use $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\infty \times (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ because there is an element of order $6$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For (1)+(2.1), consider the [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) $C_2\ast C_3\ast C_4\ast\dots\ast C_n$.

Comment: This can help: If $a$ and $b$ conmute then $|ab| = \operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.

Comment: This is related but unfortunately not very helpful https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869391902719 . It claims the notation $OC_n$ is standard for the condition you want, but I can't really find anything with it.

Comment: @HereToRelax Yes, but the group is not necessarily commutative.

Comment: @user10354138 I think it works when $n$ is a factorial number $k!$?

Comment: If your group is an infinite product of $\mathbb Z_j$ with $j\leq n$ then the only orders you can have are those dividing $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)$.

Comment: @HereToRelax $OC_n$ considers the finite groups, but I am working on infinite groups. But I think it may bring some new ideas, thank you a lot!

Comment: BTW, the word "any" in the second sentence is ambiguous. Do you mean "for some $n>2$" or "for all $n>2$"? It is good general advice to avoid using the word "any" in formal mathematics. Anyway, the answer is certainly yes when $n=3$, and possibly for all $n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for pointing this out. $n$ is a given number, and for $n=2$ the answer is yes, but how to say $n=3$ is also yes?

Comment: The last paragraph of the paper that @HereToRelax linked to claims that infinite $OC_n$ groups exist for $1\leq n\leq6$ and that it is an open problem (this was in 1991) what the largest $n$ is for which there is an infinite $OC_n$ group. I don't know whether this indicates that the authors knew that there *is* a largest such $n$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Oh, very nice! I guess I was too lazy to read :/

Comment: Oh wait, but they are just using the finite ones for the infinite ones aren't they? It doesn't seem like they are using the infiniteness.

Comment: I also find a survey "Properties of Finite and Periodic Groups Determined by Their Element Orders (A Survey)" talking about the set of orders of all elements $\{o(x)\mid x \in G\}$. But it also seems not very helpful..

Comment: @VicaYang "free product" != "free abelian product".

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks I got it, 1+(2.1) is solved

Answer (score 4):

For $n=2$ we can take $G$ to be a subdirect product of  infinitely many copies of $A_4$, where $G$ has an infinite normal elementary abelian $2$-subgroup $N$ with $|G/N|=3$ and $C_G(N)=N$.

For $n=4$, do a similar construction with $S_4$, with $G/N = S_3$.

For  $n=5$, there is a similar example with $G/N = A_5$, where (as $A_5$-module) $N$ is a direct sum of infinitely many copies of the $2$-dimensional module over ${\mathbb F}_4$ (i.e. the natural module for ${\rm SL}(2,4) \cong A_5$).

For $n=6$ we can just take the direct product of the $n=4$ example with $C_2$.

I don't know about higher $n$, but it is known that the only finite group with element orders $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ is $A_7$, so it is perhaps unlikely
that infinite examples exist.